# Validation Method that calls itself in java

Tags: java, validation, try-catch

I trying to understand why the method validateItemquantity eventually crashes with an `NumberFormatException` error. The logic seem correct, but something is not right. Its suppose to keep asking the user to reenter until it gets an valid input and then return that valid input.

```
String validateItemquantity(String itemQuantity) {
       try{ 
           Integer.parseInt(itemQuantity);

          }
       catch (NumberFormatException e) {
           itemQuantity = JOptionPane.showInputDialog 
                                   ("Invalid item quantiy, please enter a new Value");
           validateItemquantity(itemQuantity);
          }
       return itemQuantity ;
```

Method that calls it:

```
 private void bnPurchaseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    String itemCode, validItemquantity ; 
    int itemQuantity, itemPrice, itemCost, totalCost ;

    validItemquantity =  validateItemquantity(itemQuantityinput.getText());
    itemQuantity = Integer.parseInt(validItemquantity);
    itemCode = itemCodeinput.getText();
    itemPrice = catalog.searchCatalog(itemCode);
    itemCost = payment.calculateItemcost(itemQuantity,itemPrice);
    totalCost = payment.calculateTotalcost(itemCost);
```

Comment: It seems validItemquantity is either null (or) String, which causes NumberFormatException.

Comment: Try `Integer.parseInt(itemQuantity.trim())`;

Comment: This is not the right way to loop for input. Use a while(true) loop with a conditional break. (That may or may not be the issue causing your exception, but it is *an* issue.)

Comment: @Adesh - `Integer.parseInt()` will trigger the `NumberFormatException` if the String is not a parseable number, presumably because is not in a valid number format. ___ Try changing your error-message dialog to print the originating `String`, then reply whatever it prints in a comment. ___ It will probably either be `null` or contain invalid characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it return the result of the parse or call itself on exception, like this:

```
String validateItemQuantity(String itemQuantity) {
   try { 
       return Integer.parseInt(itemQuantity); // returns if no exception
   } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
       return validateItemQuantity(JOptionPane.showInputDialog 
                               ("Invalid item quantiy, please enter a new Value"));
   }
}
```

This method will only return a valid response; it loops forever until it gets a valid response.

A few comments have mentioned that the above code may be attacked by the user entering bad data millions of times and blowing the stack. I say "let them", but if you really want to make it safe, use a while loop:

```
String validateItemQuantity(String itemQuantity) {
    while (true) {
        try { 
            return Integer.parseInt(itemQuantity); // returns if no exception
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
           itemQuantity = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
               "Invalid item quantiy, please enter a new Value"));
        }
    }
}
```

It adds a `while` loop, so the code complexity increases slightly, but it's only couple of extra lines of code and it is more efficient and safe.

Comment: It will loop until it exhausts the stack, at least. :P It's not that big of an issue, it just feels like you fixed and polished a square wheel.

Comment: If the user enters incorrect input enough times to cause a StackOverflowException, then they're either incompetent or trying to hack your program.

Comment: Is this best practice or would the better thing be to use a while (true) loop?

Comment: This code is fine - I like the brevity of this. True it uses the stack, but there's no way a user entering data could exhaust it. He would die of old age or boredom long before that. If stack/hack is an issue just use a while - see edited answer

Answer (score 0):

> I trying to understand why the method validateItemquantity eventually crashes with an NumberFormatException error.

You need to post the stack-trace for investigating. Better yet, use a debugger to see where you get the exception.

> The logic seem correct

It seems correct, but convoluted :) Is there a reason you have to use recursion? How about something simple like this?

```
String validateItemquantity(String itemQuantity) {
    while (true) {
       try { 
           Integer.parseInt(itemQuantity);
           return itemQuantity;
       }
       catch (NumberFormatException e) {
           validateItemquantity(itemQuantity);
       }
       itemQuantity = JOptionPane.showInputDialog 
            ("Invalid item quantity, please enter a new Value");
    }
}
```

Comment: You call this simple? It has an infinite loop **and** recursion! The line `itemQuantity = ...` is dead code. It will also fail to compile because the method doesn't always return a value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're changing references. `itemQuantity` is assigned a different reference within each "catch" block. That change of reference does not update the parameter passed into the function. It's basically a "pass-by-value" error.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `validateItemQuantity` returns either the original string that was passed in (if valid), or the string acquired by the first showing of the input box from the catch-block (unconditionally). All the recursive calls and all their input boxes are wasted.